# How to sort negative numbers in the quick sort algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the quick sort algorithm to sort a random of list of any numbers, but do not know how to sort negative numbers as well, which part of the code should I work on?

Didn't know what to do, commenting out the change of code will help out a lot.

Expected Results:

```
>>> quickSort([3,5,-3,-1,1,2,4])
[-3, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Actual Results:

```
>>> quickSort([3,5,-3,-1,1,2,4])
[1, 2, -3, -1, 3, 4, 5]
```

```
def quickSort(numList):

    n=len(numList)
    if n<=1:
        return numList
    x, left, right = numList[0], 0, n-1
    while left<right:
        if numList[left]<=x:    
            left+=1
        else:
            numList[left], numList[right]  =  numList[right], numList[left]
            right -=1
    numList[0], numList[left] = numList[left], numList[0]
    quickSort(numList[:left])
    quickSort(numList[left+1:])
    return numList
```

Comment: what would make negative numbers any different?

Comment: What went wrong when you used negative numbers?

Comment: Hi guys, I edited to show the actual and expected results if that helps!

Comment: Why do you think it's not working just for negative numbers?  Your recursive calls modify new lists, not the original list.

Comment: I am not quite sure why it's not working, and would you elaborate on what you mean by modifying new lists and not the original list?

Comment: `numList[:left]` creates a copy of `numList` with the specified range of elements.  Same with `numList[left+1:]`.  Consequently, calling `quicksort` on them has no effect on the original `numList` that was supplied.  Thus you end up with the result of partitioning around only a single pivot (in your test case, 3).  This has nothing to do with negative numbers, which a few more test cases could have easily shown.

Comment: And in general, I'd suggest an Occam's Razor mentality: it's more likely that your implementation simply doesn't work than it is that it works for everything but negative numbers.  Don't jump to conclusions (and then suggest such unproven conclusions in your question).

Answer (score 4):

The unexpected result is not caused by negative number, but several bugs in your quick sort algorithm. I have fixed them just based on your version, although it is not the best version to implement. you can compare revised code and read the comment to understand.

A fatal bug I want to point out is, `numList[:left]` will slice and generate a new array, it will not effect origin array when you sort on it. So you should pass the `array`, and `left`, `right` index to `quickSort` function, not slice.

```
def quickSort(numList, left, right):
    # change check condition to left < right
    # n = len(numList)
    # if n <= 1:
    #     return numList
    if left < right:
        # copy left, right, it will used later
        low, high = left, right

        # it is better to abstract this block to a new function, like partition
        # pick a pivot number
        x = numList[left]
        while left < right:
            # you should use two-pointer to swap
            while left < right and numList[right] >= x:
                right -= 1
            numList[left] = numList[right]

            while left < right and numList[left] <= x:
                left += 1
            numList[right] = numList[left]
            # if numList[left] <= x:
            #     left += 1
            # else:
            #     numList[left], numList[right] = numList[right], numList[left]
            #     right -= 1

        # assign back the pivot number
        numList[left] = x
        # numList[0], numList[left] = numList[left], numList[0]

        # use origin arr and index, not slice 
        quickSort(numList, low, left-1)
        quickSort(numList, left+1, high)
        # quickSort(numList[:left])
        # quickSort(numList[left + 1:])
    return numList
```

test and output

```
arr = [3, 5, -3, -1, 1, 2, 4]
print(quickSort(arr, 0, len(arr)-1))
# [-3, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )